# Retrieve data from LIKE Query

Tags: sql, syntax

I have a database table named 'manufact' which has columns like below.

[image]

Whats the SQL command to Retrieve the manufacturer details whose names start with letter A to N.

Comment: `where left(Name,1) between 'A' and 'N'`  assuming Left supported and all capital letters, but you could upper() the left if needed.  though it may not be necessary if the database is case insensitive.

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All I want is to retrieve all the details of the table where 'manu_name' starts with letter 'A' to letter 'N'.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from manufacturer where manu_name like '[A-N]%';
```